# What's the best way to select data only appearing in one of two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select

If I have two tables such as this:

```
CREATE TABLE #table1 (id INT, name VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES (1,'John')
INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES (2,'Alan')
INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES (3,'Dave')
INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES (4,'Fred')
CREATE TABLE #table2 (id INT, name VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #table2 VALUES (1,'John')
INSERT INTO #table2 VALUES (3,'Dave')
INSERT INTO #table2 VALUES (5,'Steve')
```

And I want to see all rows which only appear in one of the tables, what would be the best way to go about this?

All I can think of is to either do:

```
SELECT * from #table1 except SELECT * FROM #table2
UNION
SELECT * from #table2 except SELECT * FROM #table1
```

Or something along the lines of:

```
SELECT id,MAX(name) as name  FROM
(
SELECT *,1 as count from #table1 UNION ALL
SELECT *,1 as count from #table2
) data 
group by id
HAVING SUM(count) =1
```

Which would return Alan,Fred and Steve in this case.

But these feel really clunky - is there a more efficient way of approaching this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id)     id,
       coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) name
from   #table1 t1
       full outer join #table2 t2
         on t1.id = t2.id
where  t1.id is null
        or t2.id is null
```

The full outer join guarantees records from both sides of the join. Whatever record that does not have in both sides (the ones you are looking for) will have `NULL` in one side or in other. That's why we filter for `NULL`.

The `COALESCE` is there to guarantee that the non `NULL` value will be displayed.

Finally, it's worth highlighting that repetitions are detected by ID. If you want it also to be by name, you should add `name` to the `JOIN`. If you only want to be by name, join by `name` only. This solution (using `JOIN`) gives you that flexibility.

BTW, since you provided the `CREATE` and `INSERT` code, I actually ran them and the code above is a fully working code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - would this have issues of scalability on larger tables / multiple columns? My actual tables would have around 2 - 10 million rows each with up to around 15 or so columns, and I would think that a cross join would make things a bit slow?

Comment: If you have indexes on the `join` fields you will do **a lot better** in performance than using `EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT`.

Comment: If I'm joining on multiple columns would I need a covering index across all of the join columns, or would it be okay to have lots of single column indexes?

Comment: @Adrian: No wonder. Join is typically done on a couple of columns, while UNION et al. check all the columns.

Comment: Well, I'm not an "index expert", but I believe you should start with one index for all joining fields. Since you have the data at hand, you have a great teacher here: trial and error. Experiment. A lot of learning there!

Comment: Precisely, @Andriy M! This is why using join is potentially faster than `UNION`, `EXCEPT`, `INTERSECT` ...

Comment: Thanks for the help but alas I am unable to create indexes and so would need to ask our DBAs to do so, and for that I need to be able to say which would be the best (chicken and egg situation really I know!)

Comment: I see. Well, since you have a DBA, why don't you ask **him/her**? Your DBA should know (ooo, that sounded like The Beatles!). Explain what you are trying to achieve. BTW, have you even tried to run the query just the way it is? Take your shot and see how it goes.

Comment: I have run the query and it seems to be working much better even without having all of the appropriate indexes - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`EXCEPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) and `INTERSECT`:

```
-- All rows
SELECT * FROM #table1 
UNION
SELECT * FROM #table2
EXCEPT -- except
(
  -- those in both tables
  SELECT * FROM #table1 
  INTERSECT
  SELECT * FROM #table2
)
```

Not sure if this is any better than your `EXCEPT` and `UNION` example...

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, name
from
 (select *, count(*) over(partition by checksum(*)) as cc
  from (select *
        from #table1
        union all
        select *
        from #table2
       ) as T
 ) as T
where cc = 1
```